# how to sum values in order of each day that seen(first day, second day ,etc) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame like this:

```
     id                 Date       Volume      Price     Values(Volume*Price)
    56033738624803469  20170111    1          943339    943339
    56033738624803469  20170111    10         919410    9194100
    56033738624803469  20170112    1          919410    919410
    56033738624803469  20170112    5          954999    4774955
    4659957480182399   20170207    1          1000000   1000000
    4659957480182399   20170208    5          1000000   5000000
    4659957480182399   20170208    40         1000000   40000000
```

I want to compute and plot the following computation for the first 100 days for each ID:

1. compute average values per day over the first 100 days
2. Plot this for all of Ids
3. Afterwards, the plot should like this:

[image: Desired plot]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cozR.png)

This is what I've done so far:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Id', 'Date']).sum()
```

The result is :

```
                               Index   Volume        Price        Values
Id               Date                                               
1745829084228393 20170207      1     1000    1000000.0  1.000000e+09
                 20170208   5151   999000  101000000.0  9.990000e+11 
                 20170403      1       12    1000100.0  1.200120e+07
                 20170408      1       12    1000000.0  1.200000e+07
                 20170417      1      500    1000000.0  5.000000e+08
                 20170423      3    14500    2000000.0  1.450000e+10
                 20170507     10    35000    4000000.0  3.500000e+10
                 20170510     21    49051    6000000.0  4.905100e+10
                 20170529      1        4    1000000.0  4.000000e+06
2888358730233310 20170212    820  2000000   40000000.0  2.000000e+12
2929948497881810 20170207   1830  1500000   60000000.0  1.500000e+12
                 20170208    903   700000   42000000.0  7.000000e+11
                 20170212   1176   800000   48000000.0  8.000000e+11
3715246194918044 20150509     66     1008   11000000.0  1.008000e+09
```

Now I want to calculate the average of first , second ,... of each ID for Values, for example:

```
 Date_Order     avg_Sum_Values(= summation first date of each id /(number of ids))
 first_Date     875.5 e+9 
 second_Date    849.5 e+9
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more succinct way to do this, but if you're alright doing a few merges, you can do it one step at a time:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   Id       Date  Value
0   1 2017-04-08      1
1   1 2017-04-08      1
2   1 2017-04-09      2
3   2 2017-04-08      3
4   2 2017-04-09      6
5   2 2017-04-09      4
6   3 2017-04-09     10
7   3 2017-04-09     11
8   3 2017-04-11     12

In [2]: min_dates = df.groupby('Id', as_index=False).Date.min()
   ...: df = pd.merge(df, min_dates, on='Id', suffixes=('', '_min'))
   ...: df['Date'] = ((df['Date'] - df['Date_min']) / pd.Timedelta('1 day')).apply(int)
   ...: df.groupby('Date').Value.sum()
   ...:
Out[2]:
Date
0    26
1    12
2    12
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks but i have date times range more than one day for example i have dates between 2010 up to 2017.may be my question is not clear enough.for example in your data i want to calculate sum of 'Value' for '20170408'  (=2) for 'id' 1 and sum it up with value of 20170408 of id '2' (=3) and sum it with value 20170409 (= 31) (consider that i have a large verity of days)

Comment: That's fine, all you need to do is use pd.to_datetime and pd.TimeDelta to get your types correct, and it'll handle the date magic for you. I've updated my answer again to demonstrate how to use these types correctly.